# C++ const_cast usage instead of C-style casts

Tags: c++, const-cast

Why is the following?:

```
  const int i0 = 5;
//int       i1 = const_cast<int>(i0);       // compilation error
  int       i2 = (int)i0;                   // okay

  int       i3 = 5;
//const int i4 = const_cast<const int>(i3); // compilation error
  const int i5 = (const int)i3;             // okay
```

Comment: could you add the error messages from compiler ?

Comment: invalid use of const_cast with type `int', which is not a pointer, 
   reference, nor a pointer-to-data-member type

invalid use of const_cast with type `const int', which is not a 
   pointer, reference, nor a pointer-to-data-member type

Answer (score 23):

```
  const int i0 = 5;
//int       i1 = const_cast<int>(i0);       // compilation error
  int       i2 = (int)i0;                   // okay

  int       i3 = 5;
//const int i4 = const_cast<const int>(i3); // compilation error
  const int i5 = (const int)i3;             // okay
```

The compilation errors are caused because you don't cast const away/add const. Instead, you copy i0. For that operation, no cast is required at all:

```
int i1 = i0;
const int i4 = i3;
```

The type you cast to should actually be a pointer or reference. Otherwise, using const_cast doesn't make sense since you could straight copy it. For pointers, for example, you can cast away the const, because dereferencing the pointer will yield another type for a `const T*` (yields `const T`) than for a `T*` (yields `T`). For references, the same is true: `T&` will access the object using another *this* pointer type than using `const T&`. Now what you really wanted to archive:

```
  const int i0 = 5;
//int &     i1 = const_cast<int&>(i0);      // okay (but dangerous)
  int &     i2 = (int&)i0;                  // okay (but dangerous)

  int       i3 = 5;
//const int&i4 = const_cast<const int&>(i3); // ok now and valid!
  const int&i5 = (const int&)i3;             // okay too!
```

The above can lead to undefined behavior, when you write to an originally const object through a reference to non-const (actually, merely casting and reading it isn't undefined behavior in itself. But if you're casting away const, you may also write to it, which then yields the undefined behavior)

Comment: Is it really undefined behavior to simply HAVE a non-const reference to a const object? I thought you actually had to attempt to modify it. You example doesn't access i2 at all; it just defines it.

Comment: Are there any situations where a C-style cast from (int) to (const int) or from (const int) to (int) would be useful, being that const_cast<int> and const_cast<const int> are not allowed?

Comment: kenny, no there are no situations. there are no constant rvalues of builtin type. so those would either be illegal, or just the same as "int" (depends on what the standard says, haven't looked up im in school currently)

Comment: Ahh. Very educational, thank you. Casting a constant to a reference to a non-constant just seems like lunacy.

Answer (score 5):

It's an error because the standard says it's not allowed. The standard enumerates the kinds of conversions that `const_cast` is allowed to do, and it disallows anything not on the list. It allows the following:

- Pointers
- References
- Member-pointers

Since your types aren't any of those, they're not allowed.

On the bright side, the examples you gave don't *need* `const_cast`, either.

Answer (score 1):

For the first error.  const_cast can only be used on pointer or reference types.  "int" is neither.  This may or may not be the C++ standard (couldn't find a good reference).  But it is the case for certain implementations such as MS's C++ compiler.

For the second error.  const_cast can only be used to remove a const or volatile qualifier not add it.

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz6at95h(VS.80).aspx

Comment: The const_cast operator (C++ only)
A const_cast operator is used to add or remove a const or volatile modifier to or from a type. From: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/compbgpl/v9v111/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp9.bg.doc/language_ref/keyword_const_cast.htm

Answer (score 0):

According to [CPP Reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/const_cast), the result has to be pointer or references. When using pointer, the input also needs to be a pointer. For references, you can the variables as inputs, and reference as output. The page says:

> lvalue of any type T may be converted to a lvalue or rvalue reference
> to the same type T, more or less cv-qualified. Likewise, a prvalue of
> class type or an xvalue of any type may be converted to a more or less
> cv-qualified rvalue reference.

meaning

```
/* lvalue can be converted to lvalue or rvalue references  */
int& test1 = const_cast<int&>(var);   // lvalue to l-ref; same works for class type
int&& test2 = const_cast<int&&>(var); // lvalue to r-ref; same works for class type
/* prvalues: restriction on built-in types to allow some compiler optimization */
//int&& test5 = const_cast<int&&>(1);            // prvalue of built-in not allowed
A&& test6 = const_cast<A&&>(A());                // prvalue of class type allowed
/* xvalue can be converted to rvalue references */
int&& test8 = const_cast<int&&>(std::move(var)); //xvalue of built-in
A&& test8 = const_cast<A&&>(std::move(A()));     // xvalue of class
```