# const_cast<int*> doesnt work. Why?

Tags: c++, constants

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [const_casting question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4518630/const-casting-question)

The following code tries to change the value of const int a; but it seems a and b both point to same memory address but print out different values. Can somebody explain why?

```
const int a = 5;
int *b = const_cast<int*>(&a);
*b = 7; //not working why??
cout<<"\nConst Cast: "<<a<<"  "<<&a;
cout<<"\nConst Cast: "<<*b<<"  "<<b;
cout<<"\nConst Cast: "<<a<<"  "<<&a;

/* Output
Const Cast: 5  0027F7FC
Const Cast: 7  0027F7FC
Const Cast: 5  0027F7FC
*/
```

Comment: You've told the compiler you promise not to modify the value of `a`, then you go break that promise two lines later and modify it. That's invoking undefined behavior, which for all intents and purposes means "**DON'T DO IT**".

Comment: when you did `const int a=4;` you assign `a` with a constant expression which can be evaluated at compile time, so that's why your compiler replace wherever it saw `a` with it's value. so the value of `a` changed indeed. if you tried to set `a` with a non-const expression then you will get the result you would have expected.

Answer (score 5):

`const_cast` is not there to allow you to modify a constant object, but rather to drop the const-ness of a reference/pointer to a non-const object and to be able to call old broken interfaces where the library would not modify, but took a non-const pointer. Modifying an object tha **is** const is undefined behavior.

Now on the practical test you have. Chances are that the compiler has substituted the value of *compile time constant* `a` (which you promised that was 5) into the different uses in the function. When you *print* `a` the compiler is printing `5`, not reading the value.

Answer (score 4):

You lied to the compiler.  You told it that `a` was const, so it went ahead and treated it as if it was so, replacing instances of `a` with the compile time constant `5`.

What you're doing is undefined behavior.