# const_cast cannot change the variable?

Tags: c++, const-cast

Here is the test code:

```
int main()
{
    const int a = 10;
    int * b = const_cast<int *>(&a);
    *b = 3;
    printf("%x %x %d %d",&a,b,a,*b);
}
```

it print

> 22ff18 22ff18 10 3

I want to know why *b and a print different answer? it share the same address!

Comment: This is [undefined behavior to attempt to modify a const variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22656734/how-is-a-variable-at-the-same-address-producing-2-different-values)

Comment: Undefined Behaviour. There is no way to reason about it without reference to the underling implementation. There is also very little reason to ever have it in your program. Don't cast away const.

Comment: @Mankarse Then, When should we use const_cast?

Comment: @FredLarson it is not an exact duplicate and after [I was scolded a little while ago](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266364/why-was-my-question-marked-duplicate-citing-an-existing-similar-answer) I have been more cautious with this.

Comment: @maple `const_cast` is valid if the object you're pointing to isn't `const`. For instance, `int a = 0; const int* b = &a; int* c = const_cast<int*>(b); *c = 2;` is valid, because `a` isn't `const`.

Comment: @maple [When const_cast can be used](http://stackoverflow.com/q/357600/3821804); [possible explanation of what you saw here.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4518788/3821804)

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4518630/3821804)