# const_cast for references and pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, casting

I see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/370591/859227) which explain the `const_cast<>` and says it is beneficial when pointers/references are used. However, consider the following codes:

1-

```
const_cast<SCOTCH_Num*>(xadj)
```

which I get `invalid const_cast from type 'cost label* {aka const long int *}' to type 'SCOTCH_Num* {aka int*}'`. So, pointers are casted. Isn't that?

and

2-

```
(SCOTCH_Num*)(xadj)
```

which I get `warning: use of old-style cast [-Wold-style-cast]`

You may ask about the variable definitions, but the `aka` part in the error is clear. If I have propose more details, please let me know.

Comment: There is no thing as a `const_cast` in C. Therefore, I think you talk about C++.

Comment: Beneficial may not be the right word. It's the only case where it has any use, but there's no benefits.

Comment: Beyond that, I don't get your question. I considered the two code samples, not what?

Comment: @StoryTeller: See the first code. So, pointers are casted. Isn't that? Why error then?

Comment: @mahmood const_casts are used for changing constness;  static_cast however is used for changing type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`const_cast` is only to be used for modifying const or volatile qualifiers on pointers **to the same type**. You cannot use it to cast between unrelated pointer types. A `long int *` is a pointer to an object type different than `int*`, so a `const_cast` will be ill-formed. And that's good, because you shouldn't be caught unaware when doing something risky like that.

The c-style cast will do the conversion at virtually any cost. It's a blunt tool that pays little regard to the type system. The whole reason C++ introduced different types of casts for different scenarios is to avoid this "casting at all costs" behavior. It's to give the programmer control and precision while casting.

Comment: You might want to add _"Modifying a const object through a non-const access path and referring to a volatile object through a non-volatile glvalue results in undefined behavior."_

Comment: @RichardCritten - I don't really, since it's not the subject of the question. I'd rather stay on point, which is the casts themselves. There's possible UB if we use the result of the C-style cast too, due to strict aliasing. Delving into that is a tangent as well.